# Php MySql utf8_encode / decode returns different strings

Tags: php

My mother language uses accents and I usually use the utf8_encode to utf8_decode function in php to avoid problems.

Now I've a MySql field of type varchar (utf8_bin) and another of type longtext (utf8_bin). 
Varchar returns odd characters, while longtext works good.

Is there a difference between the way they're managed by php?

```
$a = "Início";
echo utf8_encode($a)."<br>";
echo utf8_decode($a);

Using MySql field of type varchar I get

InÃ­cio
In�cio

Using MySql field of type text or longtext I get

Início

witch is the correct output I need.
```

Comment: What is the character encoding of PHP file and output ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Well I had issues with Turkish characters because of PHP file's character encoding, not only with the output's. You should also check that. Notepad++ or any IDEs allow changing that.

Comment: mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link); solved the question, as Turkish also has some strange characters, I recommend you to try :-)

Comment: If that solved your issue, that means your table's/database's mysql charset was wrong, as Ergo suggested. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you [setting the mySQL charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) before running your SQL to fetch the text? With regards to the character encoding issues, see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets), did you convert the field encoding when there was already content in the fields?

> Unfortunately, a direct conversion like that can mangle the text in
>   the database and make it unreadable, especially if there are actual
>   international characters (i.e. non-latin languages). The reasons for
>   this distortion are complicated and hard to understand, but the result
>   is that each column must be converted twice

[...]

> As you can see we first convert the LONGTEXT column to its blob-type
>   counterpart: LONGBLOB. Once this is complete, we convert it back to
>   LONGTEXT, but with our desired character set of utf8;.

It sounds like you're pretty au fait with general encoding issues, though [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684943/charset-issues-in-printing-text-from-db-table/7685067#7685067) if not.

Comment: Hello, no I've previously created the database with utf_8 encoding. Just inserted records after. I checked your links and the last one solved the question, using mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link); before query database seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Great, it usually fixes the issue

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference between the way they're managed by php?

No.